# javascript bookmarklet to click Accept on a Facebook Page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need a javascript bookmarklet that will click the "Yes" button on a facebook page for farmville (or any similar facebook game).  The page would say soemthing like "Would you like to accept this gift" and there are three buttons.  YEs, Yes and send thank you gift and No.  I want to select Yes via javascript.

Information related to the Yes button (pulled from chrome inspector)

```
<form action="" method="post" style="float: left; text-align: right; width: 30%;" id="app102452128776_form_4c96dd63e3ca077b35e0b"><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_locale" value="en_US" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_in_new_facebook" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_time" value="1284955491.9298" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_added" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_profile_update_time" value="1279260928" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_expires" value="1284962400" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_user" value="100001318363956" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_session_key" value="2.Oh1iDQtbxvGYg3vOpKpRVQ__.3600.1284962400-100001318363956" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_ext_perms" value="email,user_birthday,user_location" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_country" value="us" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_api_key" value="80c6ec6628efd9a465dd223190a65bbc" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig_app_id" value="102452128776" /><input type="hidden" name="fb_sig" value="366919f0f771b5fb47303abcb5d6055f" /> 
                <input class="inputyessubmit" type="submit" name="acceptReward" value="Yes" /> 
            </form>
```

Comment: Shady how?  I'm trying to automatically accept items.

Comment: what's wrong with clicking the yes button manually? seems like the same amount of work (no farmville exp. here).

Comment: I'm writing a script to automate the process.  This is the only step I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your snippet above, you'd take this

<s>`javascript:(function(){ var b; b=document.getElemenstByName('acceptReward'); if(b.length>0) { b[0].click(); } })()`</s>

and paste it into the address bar. This assumes the name `acceptReward` is unique to that element.

edits: try this. fixed a typo and added some additional checking. that's what I get for coding without intellisense.

```
javascript:(function(){var b=document.getElementsByName('acceptReward');for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++){if(b[j].value.match(/^Yes$/i)){b[j].click();break;}}})()
```

Comment: That is not working.  The acceptReward is not unique, but just to test I changed the acceptReward to refuseReward (which is unique in the element) and it still did not do anything.  I appreciate your help so far though, Thanks!